# Getting error when URL of external Site in Iframe  in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
alert(document.getElementById('external-site').contentWindow.location.href);
```

Hello all, this code is working in **Chrome** and showing "undefined" but in **Mozila Firefox** it is showing error.

**Error: Permission denied to access property 'href'**

Comment: What about just `contentWindow.location`? Does that not give you the same results as `.href`?

Comment: How can you say this is working for Chrome when it shows 'undefined'? Is that what you expect?

Comment: @mattytommo after removing .href it is showing Error: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.alert]

Comment: @Jochem yep if it is external site url then i need undefined. if the url in iframe is of current site then it is working correct,

Answer (score 2):

if `document.getElementById('external-site')` is referring to an iframe which is loading a page from a different domain then firefox runs into a `same-origin policy` error and you cannot access to `window.location` object

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript):

> The same origin policy prevents a document or script loaded from one origin from **getting** or setting properties of a document from another origin. This policy dates all the way back to Netscape Navigator 2.0.

Comment: Ya page is of diffrent domain. But is there something else i can do my work if the url in iframe is of current site url?

Comment: in a such case you won't get any error. Remember that same domain means same protocol + same domain (and subdomains if any) + same port

Comment: But how can i check if the current url of iframe is my site? because after some process on other site it will redirect to my site in iframe and i want to change the window location to current location of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you want to do is 'check' if it is external, why not catch the error? Seems to work in FF and Chrome. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyrRe/).

```
try {
    alert(document.getElementById('external-site').contentWindow.location.href);
}
catch (err) {
    alert("undefined");
}
```

Comment: yeah but if the domain in iframe is diffrent from domain of site then it always will show javascript error in console. So that i just need a method that is enable if only iframe have same site url. please tell if any method like this is available?

Comment: Did you try my fiddle? If the domain is different, 'alert("undefined")' will be executed and *NO error ends up in the console*. If the url links to the same site (as the containing page), the code within the `try {}` will execute. These two use cases are actually in the jsFiddle. [edit: at least, this is what happens in my versions of Chrome and Firefox]

Comment: yes but i know but i dont want to use any try catch block for this ;)
but but i think there is no more solution for this so i do this. ;)
thnx.. :)

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer, this may also help you get future questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error.

To overcome this error I used the following line of code:

`alert(document.getElementById('external-site').contentWindow.document.location.href);`